# Why is onMessage() (JMS Listener) not called during unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

From console output below, as far as I could see, my embedded ActiveMQ was initialized correctly and it is answering at 61616 port.

When I run the test below, I assume the message is successfully sent because I can debug line-by-line and see both simpleSend() and sendMessage() been ran.

I was expecting to see onMessage been triggered twice but It is not really occurring.

In the code below, when I run the unit test, I understand that:
1 - an embedded ActiveMQ with its broker is started 
2 - an instance of MyListener is passed to org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer

So, what I am missing here in order to test onMessage()?

Console

```
 INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: MemoryPersistenceAdapter
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.1 (localhost, ID:win10-cha-55866-1509636415848-0:1) is starting
 INFO | Listening for connections at: tcp://127.0.0.1:61616
 INFO | Connector tcp://localhost:61616 started
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.1 (localhost, ID:win10-cha-55866-1509636415848-0:1) started
 INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
```

Sender

```
import javax.jms.Queue;

import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

public class SampleJmsMessageSender {

    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    private Queue queue;

    public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }

    public void setQueue(Queue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void simpleSend() {
        jmsTemplate.send(queue, s -> s.createTextMessage("hello queue world"));
    }

    public void sendMessage(final MyPojo mp) {
        this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(mp);
    }
}
```

EmbeddedActiveMQ.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
                        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- Embedded ActiveMQ Broker -->
    <amq:broker id="broker" useJmx="false" persistent="false"
        useShutdownHook="false">
        <amq:transportConnectors>
            <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616" />
        </amq:transportConnectors>
    </amq:broker>
</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- JmsTemplate Definition -->
    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="defaultDestination" ref="destinationQueue" />
        <property name="messageConverter" ref="myMessageConverter" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </bean>

    <!-- ConnectionFactory Definition -->
    <bean id="connectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="amqConnectionFactory" />

    </bean>


    <bean id="destinationQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="IN_QUEUE" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="SampleJmsMessageSender" class="com.mypackage.spring.jms.SampleJmsMessageSender">
        <property name="queue" ref="destinationQueue" />
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myMessageConverter" class="com.mypackage.spring.jms.SampleMessageConverter" />

    <!-- this is the Message-Driven POJO (MDP) -->
    <bean id="messageListener" class="com.mypackage.spring.jms.MyListener">
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
        <property name="queue" ref="destinationQueue" />
    </bean>


    <!-- and this is the message listener container -->
    <bean id="jmsContainer"
        class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="destinationName" value="IN_QUEUE" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Unit Test

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class DefaultTextMessageSenderIntegrationTest {

    private static SampleJmsMessageSender messageProducer;

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:EmbeddedActiveMQ.xml", "classpath:applicationContext.xml");
        messageProducer = (SampleJmsMessageSender) applicationContext.getBean("SampleJmsMessageSender");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        messageProducer.simpleSend();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        messageProducer.sendMessage(new MyPojo("name", 1));
    }
}
```

Listener

```
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyListener implements MessageListener {

    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    private Queue queue;

    public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }

    public void setQueue(Queue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                String msg = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
                System.out.println("Received message: " + msg);
            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public MyPojo receiveMessage() throws JMSException {
        Map map = (Map) this.jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert();
        return new MyPojo((String) map.get("name"), (Integer) map.get("age"));
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
   <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <activemq.version>5.14.1</activemq.version>
        <maven-war-plugin.version>2.6</maven-war-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring JMS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ActiveMQ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>${activemq.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement> 
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>spring-jms</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement> 
        <finalName>spring-jms</finalName>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

your unit test stops before your listener (**asynchronously**) consume the message, you have to include that to the test by
Adding a `Thread.sleep(2000);` to delay the test stop

Or you add `MyListener.receiveMessage()` and remove the DMLC...

Or you put `String msg = null; of MyListener` as an instance variable and await in the test this value to be not null...

With actual code, in debug mode you can put a breakpoint on `MyListener.onMessage` to verify that the message is consumed